# Manually Generate Interaction Terms for regression in Shiny; append terms to checkboxInput

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, glm

I am trying to build a shiny page that will allow people to build a regression model with numeric by factor interaction terms and view the output.  I am able to get a model and output using only the numeric variables in my dataframe, that is, I can model Y ~ A +bX1 + bX2.... reactively,

HOWEVER, I cannot build a model where I have Y~ A + bX1 + bX2*FactorVar1 + bX3*FactorVar2 +...+...etc.  I would like to allow users to pick a numeric variable from the dataframe, pick a factor variable from the dataframe, generate the interaction term, add said interaction term to a checkboxInput, and let them add it to the regression model in the same way I am able to add my numeric variables.

I have included my attempt to do this in the server.r and ui.r files. I have created an example dataframe to illustrate my problem.

Dataframe:

```
df<- data.frame(userid=seq(1,100,1), numVar1=rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1), numVar2=rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=1),  numVar3=seq(from=1, to=300, by=3), numVar4=floor(runif(100, min=30, max=55)), factVar1=rep(c("Male", "Female"), 50), factVar2=rep(c("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange"), 25))
```

ui.r:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("This is a Shiny App to build GLM Models!"),
  uiOutput("dependent"),
  uiOutput("independent"),
  tags$hr(), 
  h5('Generate New Interaction Variables Here!'),
  uiOutput("makeFactInteract"),
  uiOutput("makeNumInteract"),
  uiOutput("interactionTerms"),
  #uiOutput("interacts"),


    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
),

mainPanel(

   tableOutput("regTab")

  )
)
))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

interacts<- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$goButton, {
term<- paste0(input$makeNumInteract, "*", input$makeFactInteract)
interacts[[(length(interacts)+1)]]<- term
goodinteracts<- noquote(paste(shQuote(interactionList(), type="cmd"), collapse = ", "))
return(goodinteracts)
    })



output$select_depVar <- renderUI({ selectInput(inputId = "depVar",
                                              label = h5("Pick Your Dependent Variable"),
                                              choices = names(df),
                                              selected =NULL)})

output$dependent <- renderUI({
selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))))
     })  

output$independent <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput("independent", "Independent (Predictor) Variables:",  names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent],names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent])
     })

  output$makeFactInteract <- renderUI({
selectInput("makeFactsInteract", "Factor Variable For Interaction:", names(which(sapply(df, is.factor))))
     })  


  output$makeNumInteract <- renderUI({
selectInput("makeNumInteract", "Numeric Variable for Interaction:",  names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent],names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent])
     })

  output$interactionTerms <- renderUI({
  observeEvent(input$goButton, {

  })
  if(is.null(interacts)){return("None")} else{
checkboxGroupInput("interactionTerms", "Interaction Terms for Model:",  goodinteracts())}
     })

runRegression <- reactive({
lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=df)
     })

    output$regTab <- renderTable({
     if(!is.null(input$independent)){
       summary(runRegression())$coefficients
     } else {
       print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
  }
     })





     }
    )
```

I am puzzled and frustrated by this, but hopefully the community can provide an answer.  Thank you in advance.

Best, 
NF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an example online from Joe Cheng that I adapted to solve my problem.  I'm grateful for his willingness to share his work.  The code I used is as follows:

server.r:

```
#########Starting the Shiny application
shinyServer(
 function(input, output, session) {
df<- fakedata


### From jcheng..he used listN as his list
#-------------------------- the main named list that will be used in     other tasks
listN<- reactiveValues()
 makeReactiveBinding("listN")
#------Rendering the list to the ui
output$uiAdded <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput('added',
            'List of combinations', 
            choices = names(listN))
            #multiple = TRUE,
            #selectize = FALSE)
 })
#----------------------------------------------------------------

observe({
  # Trigger Add actions
  input$actionBtnAdd
  isolate({
    new_selections <- c(input$makeNumInteract,input$makeFactInteract)
    new_selections_name <- new_selections %>% paste(collapse = "*")

    if(new_selections_name != "")
      listN[[new_selections_name]] <- new_selections
  })
})



#-----------------------First Variable To Select, at the top of the     sidebar--------
output$dependent <- renderUI({
selectInput("dependent", "Dependent Variable:", names(which(sapply(df,   is.numeric))))
 })  
   #-------------------------Checkbox list of all numeric variables to use---------
output$independent <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput("independent", "Independent (Predictor) Variables:",    names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent],names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent])
})
  #-------------------Factor Variable to Add to the List of Combinations --------- 
   output$makeFactInteract <- renderUI({
   selectInput("makeFactInteract", "Factor Variable For Interaction:",     names(which(sapply(df, is.factor))))
    })  

 #---------------------Numerical Variable for List of Combinations------------- 
  output$makeNumInteract <- renderUI({
selectInput("makeNumInteract", "Numeric Variable for Interaction:",  names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent],names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))[!names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))) %in% input$dependent])
  })
    #-----------This is the place to put in the listN objects....--------------


runRegression <- reactive({
if(!is.null(input$added)){
  lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"), paste("+", input$added, collapse = "+"))),data=df)
}else{
lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=df)}
  })

 output$regTab <- renderTable({
if(!is.null(input$independent)){
  summary(runRegression())$coefficients
} else {
  print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
}
  })





 }
)
```

And the ui.r:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  helpText("This is a Shiny App to build GLM Models!"),
  uiOutput("dependent"),
  uiOutput("independent"),
  tags$hr(), 
  h5('Generate New Interaction Variables Here!'),
  uiOutput("makeFactInteract"),
  uiOutput("makeNumInteract"),
  uiOutput("uiAdded"),
  #uiOutput("interactionTerms"),
  #uiOutput("interacts"),


    actionButton("actionBtnAdd", "Create Interaction Term!")
   ),

   mainPanel(

      tableOutput("regTab")

   )
  )
 ))
```